# Socket Programming using android and php

Tags: php, android, sockets

I am trying to create an Android application which connects to php server using sockets. Below is the php code I have used for implementing socket server.

```
<?php
    set_time_limit (0);
    $address = '127.0.0.1';
    $port = 8111;
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) or die('Could not bind to address');
    socket_listen($sock);
    $client = socket_accept($sock);
    $input = socket_read($client, 1024);
    $output = $input;
    socket_write($client, $output);
    socket_close($client);
    socket_close($sock);
?>
```

Android client side code:

```
package com.example.simpleclient;

import com.example.simpleclient.util.SystemUiHider;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 * 
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */
public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {
    private Button bt;
       private TextView tv;
       private Socket socket;
       private String serverIpAddress = "192.168.2.11";
       // AND THAT'S MY DEV'T MACHINE WHERE PACKETS TO
       // PORT 5000 GET REDIRECTED TO THE SERVER EMULATOR'S
       // PORT 6000
       private static final int REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT = 8111;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);
          bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
          tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
          try {
             InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
             socket = new Socket(serverAddr, REDIRECTED_SERVERPORT);
          } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
          }
          bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                   EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
                   String str = et.getText().toString();
                   PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
                   out.println(str);
                   Log.d("Client", "Client sent message");
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                   tv.setText("Error1");
                   e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                   tv.setText("Error2");
                   e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                   tv.setText("Error3");
                   e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
          });
    }


}
```

192.168.2.11 is the ip of the system I have hosted my server. I have attached a debugger screenshot where my android code break. Please do have a look.

I am not able to connect android app to php server

[image: error image]

Comment: And your problem is.... ?

Comment: its not working. the android app is not working. It breaks at the point shown in the picture

Comment: is there a stacktrace? I guess you have not added internet permissions or you might be getting NetworkOnMainThreadException. you cannot do network operations on UI thread. You need to use Asynctask

Comment: You have bind your socket to 127.0.0.1, but you do not connect to that IP. Either bind to 192.168.2.11 as well or bind to all addresses. http://php.net/socket_bind --- Examples first: http://php.net/sockets.examples

Comment: 192.168.2.11 is my ip in local lan and 127.0.0.1 is localhost of 192.168.2.11 so it must work right?

Comment: @GeoPaul: No idea why I put links in here if you do not even read the first paragraphs of these. Sigh.

Comment: @hakre: I tried that too.. not working

Comment: @hakre I got it working :) it was some strict mode disabling my internet connectivity in Google Nexus i9250

Comment: @GeoPaul would it be possible for you to share your code? I'm trying to build a simple connection between a php server and and android app and this would help a great deal!